# Can I cook/eat unhulled malted barley?

Tags: food-safety, barley, malt

I've got a small bag of whole barley malt intended for brewing beer. After doing a bit of reading I'm getting conflicting information.  Some say the outer hull in not edible, while others say it is fine and a good source of fiber.

Take [this](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20120213215219AAwBAxv) yahoo answer for example, which indicates that unhulled wheat is the same as whole wheat.  I don't think that's true, as I'm under the impression
that the outer *hull* or *chaff* is not the same thing as the *bran* (and germ) included in whole wheat.

Is the unhulled barley edible or not?  My intended purpose is simply to mill it and simmer to as a breakfast cereal.

Comment: With **oats** the outer hull is papery enough to be unpalatable even after boiling. I'm not sure whether barley hulls would cause the same problem, but wouldn't be qt all surprised if you found little icky inedible bits floating on top of cooked barley meal. If you're milling the stuff, winnowing may be all you need to fix the potential problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winnowing

Comment: thanks for your input.  i ran an experiment this morning, ground and ate a large bowl of porridge from the stuff.  it was fine.  there were indeed some little papery particles but they were small enough in size and quantity not to disrupt the enjoyment of the food much.  no stomach ache or anything so i guess it was indeed "edible" though not exceedingly palatable.

Comment: Billynoah: Good, Oat hulls tend to be a bit to tougher, and you end up with chunks that stick unpleasantly in your throat.

Comment: Theoretically I could migrate this to homebrew and let them close as duplicate, but I think that's probably more trouble than it's worth for these comments - feel free to copy things over onto your other post.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was already posted on homebrew and the OP wanted to avoid the cross-post: http://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/17355/can-i-cook-eat-milled-barley-malt (for the record, it'd have been a fine question here too, though)

Comment: @WayfaringStranger You might consider contributing on the homebrew version of the question!